# Properties fragment query has no effect

Tags: node.js, marklogic, marklogic-10

I am using the Node.js API provided by MarkLogic to read values from the URI lexicon using the following code

```
const marklogic = require("marklogic");
const dbConn = require("../config/ml-connections");

const dbRead = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(dbConn.restReader);
const dbWrite = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(dbConn.restWriter);

const qb = marklogic.queryBuilder;
const vb = marklogic.valuesBuilder;

let termOption: string = 'exact';
let status: string = 'active';

let startDateTime = '2022-08-01T00:00:00Z';
let endDateTime = '2022-09-01T00:00:00Z';

let start = 1;
let end = 10;    

if (status === 'all') {
  termOption = 'wildcarded';
  status = '*';
}

dbRead.values.read(
  vb.fromIndexes(vb.uri())
  .where(
    qb.and(
      qb.value('status', status, qb.termOptions(termOption)),
      qb.propertiesFragment(
        qb.and(
          qb.range(qb.qname('prop:last-modified'), qb.datatype('dateTime'), '>=', startDateTime),
          qb.range(qb.qname('prop:last-modified'), qb.datatype('dateTime'), '<=', endDateTime)
        )
      )
    )
  )
  .slice(start, end)
  .withOptions({values: ['descending']})
)
.result()
.then(function (resultObject) {
  let uris: string[] = [];
  if (resultObject['values-response'].tuple) {
     for (const row of resultObject['values-response'].tuple) {
      uris.push(row['distinct-value'][0]);
    }
  }
  return uris;
})
```

This code works, but the properties fragment query here has no effect on the result of the program. What could be wrong?

PS: Ignore syntax and obvious coding errors, if any, as the code works. MarkLogic version 10.0-9.4.